# Ouput is not expected in sorting coin array values using selection sorting

Tags: java, sorting, selection

I want to sort a Coin array according to their values by using Selection sort but the output is not showing properly. The output display as some other unique format. I have tried to resolve the problem but still unable to find the solution. I have two classes CoinSelectionSorter and a Coin class. I am using Comparable interface to sort the Coin values. The entire code is like that-

**CoinSelectionSorter.java:**

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
       This class sorts an array of coins, using the selection sort
       algorithm.
 */
public class CoinSelectionSorter {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        //public void sort() {

        Coin[] list =  new Coin[] {new Coin(2, "Johan"),new Coin(5, "peter"), new Coin(1, "robin"),new Coin(15, "walker") }; // example data;

        List <Coin> p = Arrays.asList(list);
        Collections.sort(p);
        System.out.println(p);  
        list = p.toArray(list); 
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

**Coin.java:**

```java
public class Coin implements Comparable<Coin >{

    Integer r;
    String p;

    public Coin(Integer r, String p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.r = r;
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Coin test) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.r - test.r;
    }
}
```

**It gives output like:**

```
[Coin@19821f, Coin@addbf1, Coin@42e816, Coin@9304b1]
[Coin@19821f, Coin@addbf1, Coin@42e816, Coin@9304b1]
```

**But I expect output as:**

```
[2, Johan], [5, 'peter], [1, robin], [15, walker]
[1, robin], [2, Johan], [5, 'peter], [15, walker]
```

Kindly help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to override method toString in your coin class

Answer (score 2):

All you need to is override the default toString() in coin to generate the output string in desired format. Like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" + r + ", " + p + "]";
}
```

Additionally, to get the output you mentioned, you need to print the list of coins before sorting in CoinSelectionSorter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `toString()` in your class Coin:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Coin [r=" + r + ", p=" + p + "]";
}
```

This code has been generated with Eclipse. You can easily do that in **Source > Generate toString()...**